# Artifactoy Maven Repository, Generate Maven Settings only allows libs repositories

Tags: maven, artifactory

I'm a noob to Artifactoy and Maven. I've set an Artifactory cloud trail-version, and I'm able to publish resolve dependencies via a simple Maven project.

What I'm not in to: I've created a test repo called `abc-local` when I'm going to `Set Me Up` section and calling `Generate Maven Settings` I can only choose repositories that are of type virtual or containing the phrase `libs` in it.

Here is screenshot:

[image: Artifactory "Set Me Up"]

Why can't I choose my `abc-local` test repo in `Releases`, `Releases Snapshots`, ... ?

From my point of view it would make sense to deploy to repo `abc-local` and use repo `abc-local` in my Maven settings file to resolve dependencies.

Is there kind of a Maven naming convention that I'm missing? 
E.g. "Repos containing dependencies are always named `libs-release`, `libs-snapshot`

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you encountering is not a naming convention limit, but the fact that you can only choose **virtual** repositories in the "Generate Maven Settings" part. The repository you are trying to choose "abc-local" is a **local** repository and you will not be able to choose it in the "Generate Maven Settings". You may choose a virtual repository there, and then navigate to the Admin tab --> Repositories --> Virtual --> enter the configuration of the virtual repository you chose in the "Generate Maven Settings" and change the "Default Deployment Repository" to the local repository of your choosing. This will generate a Maven settings file for that will have the virtual repository as its source, which is the best practice for using Artifactory. This will enable you to pull Maven artifacts from the remote repository aggregated in the virtual and deploy new Maven packages to the local repository configured as the "Default Deployment Repository".

Hope this helps!